# Read the data-option value on select

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Using JQuery, How can I read the data-option value when an option is clicked/selected from List.

```
<span data-name="" data-select="dropdown" class="btn-group dropdown dropdown-select">
    <a data-target="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn dropdown-toggle">Select User</a>
    <a data-target="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn dropdown-toggle end"><i class="icon-arrow-down"></i></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">        
        <li class="active"><a data-option="1D" href="#">One Day</a></li>
        <li class=""><a data-option="1W" href="#">One Week</a></li>
        <li class=""><a data-option="2W" href="#">Two Weeks</a></li>

     </ul>
</span>
```

Comment: Are you using bootstrap?

Comment: the question is tagged `twitter-bootstrap`, you can assume he does ;)

Comment: @Pascamel  It wasn't originally.

Comment: @thatidiotguy my bad ;) i opened the question right between your question and david's questionm sorry for that guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("ul.dropdown-menu a").click(function(){
    alert($(this).data("option"));
});
```

Comment: Exactly What I wanted. Can't accept for another 7 minutes. Will accept it shortly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this on

```
$("ul.dropdown-menu a").on("click",function(){
     alert($(this).data("option"));
});
```

As `click` is not working when element added after dom  is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
<li class="active"><a data-option="1D" href="#" onclick="getDataOption(this);">One Day</a></li>

var getDataOption = function (node) {
    var value = node.getAttribute("data-option");
    console.log(value);
    return value;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("ul.dropdown-menu li").click(function(){

   alert($(this).attr("data-option"));
});
```